# How do I change the css overflow property of the HTML with javascript

Tags: javascript, css

at the moment i have the following css

```
html{
overflow : hidden;
}
```

how can i change overflow to 'scroll' with javascript?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**With jQuery:**

```
$('html').css({overflow: 'scroll'});
```

**Simple JavaScript**

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.overflow = "scroll";
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: That would be jQuery, not Javascript.

Comment: jQuery is JavaScript :)

Answer (score 3):

For one thing set the `body` **not** `html`

To change it to `scroll` do this:

```
document.body.style.overflow = "scroll";
```

Comment: @user521180 -- then what did you ask?